# Downloaded Panorama background image is cropped to screen size

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

If I set the Panorama.Background image brush source to a URL of a photo out on the internet, the image is centered and cropped, rather than starting at the left edge and bleeding off the screen to the right, widescreen style.

If I set the source as a local pack URI, its fine.

Smells like a bug.

Anyone got a simple workaround? Microsoft should be equipping us with a working SDK that allows us to create experiences at least as good as the phone's hubs.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The problem appears not to be images on the web, but images that are smaller than the screen size of the phone - all my web-hosted images are quite small for bandwidth reasons.

Taking my original background art 1024x768 and halving its size results in the phone cropping the right edge of the image.

**UPDATE 2**

Found someone else with the same problem:

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/78770/615061.aspx

**UPDATE 3**

http://www.lukepuplett.com/2012/05/windows-phone-panorama-background-image.html

Side-by-side images demonstrate the bug, clearly. I'll throw it over to Cliff on the team in Redmond and see what he thinks.

It's a problem I've found since my earliest days with the phone, and I assumed it'd be quite a well-known issue. So I expected people to quickly say "Oh yeah, that old chestnut, you need to do XYZ."

Thanks for the -3, everyone. Keep up the good work.

Comment: You should investigate a little further before you make accusations about bugs

Comment: Can you provide an example / way to reproduce this?

Comment: @Matt Don't why you got 3 votes, my question says "set the Panorama.Background image brush source to a URL of a photo out on the internet" -- it now seems that the image just needs to be smallish.

Comment: My comment was because you claimed a bug with just a vague description of how to recreate it. If it happens with any image you coudl have said so. If not, then some help in recreating the issue would be useful. As would an image (which you've now added)

Comment: Actually, OP is quite right. When loaded dynamically, even large (900x600) image with `Stretch.None` gets cropped to size of ONE panorama item instead of all. Putting it into XAML works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Before running around with "IT'S A BUG!" claims, I would do my research.

That being said, you are downloading an image, and most likely using a combo of `BitmapImage`/`ImageBrush`. Now, `ImageBrush` has a [Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.stretch.aspx) property and that is where you have to look.

Comment: The fact that your original questinos included no details or evidence of any. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: This is a problem I've known about since my first week with WP7, I've just never prioritised fixing it. While tweaking today, I thought I'd finally ask. Its such an obvious issue, so easily discovered, that I guess I didn't expect to have to spell it out. It appears that not many developers dynamically set their panorama images (to small images that are more suited to phone bandwidth). I'm rather surprised by the hammering such a question has taken, compared to many poor questions on SO and assume its because I said bad things about Microsoft (for whom I used to work).

Answer (score 0):

The panorama background is intended to be a rich, high quality image.

I would expect what you're seeing ("inconsistent" resizing) if you're using an image smaller than the space you're filling and not specifying how it should be stretched.

If you're claiming a bug, what is the behaviour you're expecting?
Based on your blog post (liked in update 3) it seems you're expecting a different default stretch behaviour for an image when used in the background in a panorama. As a general rule, introducing inconsistencies or conditional defaults is likely to introduce more confusion and work in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'd expect the two images on my blog post to look the same, regardless of the source bitmap size. I take your point about using a high-quality image, but the unexpected cropping still stands. Whether an image had to be shrunk to fit or enlarged, one would expect the final outcome to look the same, excluding blurring/pixellation.

Comment: @LukePuplett my guess is that the cropping is due to using a Uniform stretch to one of a pre-defined width that is based on the number of panoramaitems